# How to use a variable from page you loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Hello!**

I want to use a variable on my website from a page I loaded using get:

```
    $.get("fetchData.php", function( data ) {
         //I want to use the variable `classes`
    }, 'html');
```

The page I am loading has the following variable:

[image: The variable I want to use]

This can't just be copied since it changes every few weeks.

My question is how do I use that variable on my index.php?

So:
I am on index.php I load fetchData.php and I want to use the classes variable from the loaded page. How do I do that?

Comment: You mean `data.split("classes = [")[1].split("]")[0]` ? - do you have access to have fetchData return classes as a JSON object?

Comment: Is there a reason you are returning HTML with embedded javascript? Couldn't you return a JSON type instead with just this data? (cleaner, better performance).

Comment: @Curt Sadly enough, I can't modify the page, the page is a navigation that contains the classes variable I could extract it using PHP but I have no idea how

Comment: Marked it duplicate due to your comment about using PHP to extract the data

Answer (score -3):

The easiest way is to use `eval`

```
$.get("fetchData.php", function( data ) {
    eval(data);

    console.log(classes);
}, 'html');
```

Comment: Only if var classes = [...] is the only thing returned